# Why does jQuery need `getWindow(doc)` here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the [source for jQuery's `offset()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.1/src/offset.js#L109), why can't it just use `window` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case the element actually isn't on `window`. For example, it might be in an iFrame, or a popup.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a cross-browser compatible library, so they implement a lot of wrapper functions like that one which are contextually aware of both the document markup and the browser. That function exists so that it always returns the window parent of the element(s) in the collection.